# Location of move mail folder items in Outlook

Tags: windows, exchange, outlook

Can anyone confirm where in Windows 10, Outlook 2016 or Exchange on premise the list of folders that appear when a user right clicks on a email message and selects Move is generated from?

I've tried searching online, in the registry on my workstation and on Exchange but cannot locate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to confirm if you are looking for a way to find out the location of moved message items in outlook?

If so, I have read a blog and here are some solutions provided:

- Method 1: Search nearby folders
- Method 2: Full Folder list
- Method 3: Search for an item with Instant Search
- Method 4: Search for an item with Windows Search
- Method 5: VBA macro: Find a folder by its name

For more details: [Accidentally moved a folder and cannot find it](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/accidentally-moved-a-folder-and-cannot-find-it)

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are correct in what I'm looking for but with a slight caveat, it appears the user has moved the messages to a public folder by accident, but so far I've been unable to locate this folder.

Comment: Use Instant Search feature for Public Folders, steps in the blog for your reference: https://kb.intermedia.net/Article/21513